# Email sent time displaying amqp (Rabbitmq ) start time

Tags: php, email, header, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using Rabbitmq(amqp) and here is the code snippet ,

```
 fucntion sendMail(){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $connection = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS, VHOST);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare(EQUE_NAME, false, true, false, false);
    $callback = function($msg) {
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        $temp = json_decode($msg->body);
        $this->email->from(FROM, FROM_NAME);
        $this->email->to($temp->to);
        //$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //$this->email->Date($dt);
        $this->email->subject($temp->subject);
        $email = $this->load->view('email/' . $temp->template, $temp->params, TRUE);
        $this->email->message($email);
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            echo 'Your email was sent on ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    };
  }
```

And i'm just passing data to this function ,

```
 sendMail($email, SUBJECT_ACC_ACTIVATION, $signup);
```

So the issue is when the email sends, it shows wrong sent time.
It shows the time when queue started!